# Deploy ruby on rails app with passenger and apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I want to deploy my ruby on rails application on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 server 
I have done the following:

**Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)**

*rvm install ruby*

*gem install rails*

*gem install passenger*

*passenger-install-apache2-module*

then I added the following line on my httpd.conf file

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.50/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.50
     PassengerDefaultRuby /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby
   </IfModule>
```

alos I added the following to my httpd.conf

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.whatever.com
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /var/www/whatever/public    
  <Directory /var/www/whatever/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
     # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
     #Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

**Additional info** 
*rvm 1.25.31*

I restarted the httpd and I cannot see my app running on whatever.com
I have bought the domain and redirected it to the IP of my machine. 
**What is wrong?**

Comment: Two questions: What can you see when you go to that URL? Also, what do you see when you type the ip address of your server into the browser?

Comment: Answer to both questions : This webpage is not available

Comment: Is anything appearing in /etc/httpd/logs/error_log or /etc/httpd/logs/access_log ?

Comment: Also, this may seem like a very basic question but is your rails app in /var/www/whatever ? - Also, can you get to the app with rails s?

Comment: Its no access log error but  I have error_log files with this line and some other stuff agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.6195/generation-0/request

Comment: yes my application is in /var/www and i can start rails s, (WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done)

Comment: The log line doesn't look like an error. Try www.whatever.com:3000 with your rails server running, just to see if apache is the issue.

Comment: Well Its the same situation This webpage is not available both with ip and URl and port 3000

Comment: [ip]:3000 isn't showing you the rails app? You're a little out of my expertise but you may have a firewall rule keeping this from working. First check is that you can ping the server ip from another box `ping 192.168.0.5` or whatever the ip is. Then log in to your router, make sure there is a rule allowing http traffic on port 80 (for apache) and port 3000 (for dev server) of your server.

Comment: Thank you for useful tips, the port 80 was closed ! now its open and I get Internal Server Error

Comment: That's great, I'll pop it in as an answer so it's easier to find.

Comment: The internal server error is probably an issue with your app, standard rails debugging here, check /log/production.log, make sure the database is running and migrated etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of reasons why this can happen, @user1876128 had some internal network issues and it wasn't acutally apache at fault.

For this apache setup to work, your network needs to allow http traffic to port 80 of your server box.

It's also advisable to allow traffic on port 3000, so you can run up a rails dev server on the same address (plus :3000) to check any changes before they're up.

You can log in to most domestic routers by pointing your browser at 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1, then using the password (which is either written on your router, or the default password you can find online, or you've already changed it). And setting up a service for port 80 and your server box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment the line indicated below and restart your apache service (`sudo service apache2 restart` or similar `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`)

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.whatever.com
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /var/www/whatever/public    
  <Directory /var/www/whatever/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
     # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
 --->    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

This is a common issue with the default stuff from passenger. Chances are you're on a newer version of `apache` which means **# Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:** would apply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it did not help I have internal server error

Comment: Check your logs. It could because you're missing the `secrets.yml` file or haven't set the production environment variables yet.